# Background is not staying at full 100%

Tags: css

Restricting the height of the body to 100% of the screen height is causing the background not to stay at full 100%

How is that fixed. https://jsfiddle.net/3cgqpkrf/

`Background no-repeat;` is causing the background not to stay at 100%.

Background attachment fixed has problems on mobile.

https://css-tricks.com/the-fixed-background-attachment-hack/

I think it may be able to be seen in the snippet I provided.

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[image]

Snippet Full Screen:
[image]

```js
const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const config = {};
  let player = null;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const frameContainer = document.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer, config.playlist);
  }

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
    shufflePlaylist(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playlist) {

    const config = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      width: 640
    };
    config.playerVars = {
      autoplay: 0,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      loop: 1,
      playlist,
      rel: 0
    };
    config.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };
    player = new YT.Player(video, config);

  }

  function init(videos) {
    config.playlist = videos.join();
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

videoPlayer.init([
  "0dgNc5S8cLI",
  "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
  "CHahce95B1g",
  "2VwsvrPFr9w"
]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fade 10s ease-in 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

iframe {
  user-select: none;
}



.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="video video-frame"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you are restricting the height of the body to 100% of the screen height

Comment: How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

add the background to the container:

```js
const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const config = {};
  let player = null;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const frameContainer = document.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer, config.playlist);
  }

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
    shufflePlaylist(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playlist) {

    const config = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      width: 640
    };
    config.playerVars = {
      autoplay: 0,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      loop: 1,
      playlist,
      rel: 0
    };
    config.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };
    player = new YT.Player(video, config);

  }

  function init(videos) {
    config.playlist = videos.join();
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

videoPlayer.init([
  "0dgNc5S8cLI",
  "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
  "CHahce95B1g",
  "2VwsvrPFr9w"
]);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
  display: flex;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fade 10s ease-in 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

iframe {
  user-select: none;
}



.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="video video-frame"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
background-size: contain;
```

```js
const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const config = {};
  let player = null;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const frameContainer = document.querySelector(".video");
    videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer, config.playlist);
  }

  function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
    shufflePlaylist(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playlist) {

    const config = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      width: 640
    };
    config.playerVars = {
      autoplay: 0,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      loop: 1,
      playlist,
      rel: 0
    };
    config.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };
    player = new YT.Player(video, config);

  }

  function init(videos) {
    config.playlist = videos.join();
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = onYouTubeIframeAPIReady;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

videoPlayer.init([
  "0dgNc5S8cLI",
  "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
  "CHahce95B1g",
  "2VwsvrPFr9w"
]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #102eff, #d2379b);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fade 10s ease-in 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

iframe {
  user-select: none;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="curtain">
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="video video-frame"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still happens: Seen Here: https://i.imgur.com/w6Dts2S.png